# Javascript - How to check if a string contains escape sequence

Tags: javascript, string, hex

I have a string lets say:

```
let b = "\x41";
```

How can I check with javascript if `b` contains `\x` ?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: There's no escape sequence to test for. The content of `b` is just a capital `A` (`"\x41" === "A" // true)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346503/what-is-the-opposite-of-the-xy-problem). What is the goal? What are you actually trying to do? A string doesn't contain "an escape sequence". That term doesn't make any sense. A string just has some content. Some of that content can be represented as an escape sequence *in a string literal* but the string literal is not the final content. `"a"` just creates a string with content `a`. Same thing with `"\x61"`. As does `"\a"`. But there is not backwards mapping of what created the content.

Comment: @Andreas This issue is hard to search for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test an escape sequence, you need to have the Raw string

I do wonder why I do not get 0 but 1 here

```js
const b = String.raw`\x41`;

console.log(JSON.stringify(b),"\\\\x",JSON.stringify(b).indexOf("\\\\x"))
```

Comment: `b` will be `\\x41`. How is this equivalent to `\x41` from OP?

Comment: It was \x41 from the start, stringifying will reveal that

Comment: @mplungjan thanks, that helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can not get the string back or search for `\x`, because it is an [escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_notation) for

> \x*XX*
> …where *XX* is exactly 2 hex digits in the range 00–FF; e.g., `\x0A` is the same as \n (LINE FEED); `\x21` is "!"

> Unicode code point between U+0000 and U+00FF (the Basic Latin and Latin-1 Supplement blocks; equivalent to ISO-8859-1)

The result is an ordinary string with characters without escape sequences.

```js
let b = "\x41";

console.log(b);
console.log(JSON.stringify(b));
```

Answer (score 1):

`\x41` seems to be the letter `A` when I test this code in a browser. You cannot check if `b` has an escape sequence because JavaScript automatically makes `\x41` into the letter `A`. You can, however, check if `b` has the letter `A`.

```js
let b = "\x41";
b.indexOf("A") != -1 // Check if b contains 'A'
// Returns true
b.indexOf("\x41") != -1 // Check if b contains escape sequence '\x41'
// Returns true
"A".indexOf("\x41") != -1 // Check if the string 'A' contains the escape sequence '\x41'
// Returns true
```